# Error upon trying to insert into SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

So once again I'm having a little issue with the database stuff for my Pokémon-related app, now that I'm revisiting that part of the app development... a relatively new (the database class which is perhaps where the problem lies is almost up to date [see fix mentioned below]) version  of my eclipse project is here : http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/429262/PokeUtility.zip

So, the problem is, I added this code to my mainactivity just to test to see if I can put data in the DB:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this) ;
db.addPokemon(new Pokemon(001, "Bulbasaur", "Grass", "Poison")) ;
```

but what happens is it seems to be throwing SQLiteException like so (http://oi47.tinypic.com/332v49c.jpg)
It seems to be saying there is no "type2" column in the table in my database? :/
Did I not set something up right in the DatabaseHandler class? Oh, btw seeing as I assume it matters: given that I linked a slightly out of date version of the project there is one correction to make: `DatabaseHandler's` onCreate should read as:

```
String CREATE_POKEMON_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POKEMON + "("
            + KEY_DEX_NO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE2 + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_POKEMON_TABLE);
```

I believe the version in the linked zip file has a comma missing from the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your create query, you are missing space behind `type2` column. Actually you have this:

```
+ KEY_TYPE2 + "TEXT" + ")";
```

Add space and it should works(now you need to re-create your db). Corrected query:

```
String CREATE_POKEMON_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POKEMON + "("
            + KEY_DEX_NO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_TYPE2 + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's another problem or did I just not do everything right...:/ Can you explain how I recreate the db?

Comment: are you still around? If not, could someone else answer my question in the comment above?

Comment: @TheIceMage unistall application also with all data related with it and install again.

Comment: Ok, I have done that, currently waiting for emulator to restart...hoping it works fine now.

Comment: Ok, FINALLY after fiddling with the code a bit more it works :D Thanks for the initial help. That is, I had added a statement to print result to logcat too and that was throwing exceptions...but all is well now.